# sudo apt-install can't find linux-hwe-5.4-headers-5.4.0-51

Tags: 18.04, apt, software-installation

Running

```
$ sudo apt install
```

Results in this error.

```
$ The package linux-hwe-5.4-headers-5.4.0-51 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

Any ideas how to resolve?

Details for $cat /etc/apt/sources.list

```
mike@MikeUbuntu3:~$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS _Bionic Beaver_ - Release amd64 (20190805)]/ bionic main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal universe
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates universe
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main universe restricted multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main multiverse restricted universe #Added by software-properties
```

Comment: I also tried to run

```
sudo apt-get install -f linux-hwe-5.4-headers-5.4.0-51
```

But get same error

```
E: The package linux-hwe-5.4-headers-5.4.0-51 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

Comment: Run `sudo apt install -f`

Comment: Tried -f.  Got same issue.

Comment: Run `sudo apt update` and try again.

Comment: `sudo apt install` needs an argument.  Working in `apt` you should always first start with `sudo apt update` so you have the current list of software

Comment: ```sudo apt update``` was successful.  Lot's of successes on gets.

```sudo apt install -f``` had same failure.

Comment: Don't just tell us you had a failure -- edit your question and include the full unredacted output.

Comment: ```sudo apt install -f``` results in 
```E: The package linux-hwe-5.4-headers-5.4.0-51 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.```

Comment: `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` please add it to your question. https://askubuntu.com/posts/1296464/edit   not as comment.

Comment: Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should Edit your question to add information. By updating your Question, and using the formatting buttons, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `bionic-security` and `bionic-updates` from your sources.list file (this missing package is provided by `bionic-updates`).

Run the following commands to fix this problem.

First make a backup of your sources.list file:

```
sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sourceslistbackup
```

Now, add the missing lines:

```
echo 'deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted universe multiverse' | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
echo 'deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted universe multiverse' | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Finally, update and finish your upgrades:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install --reinstall linux-hwe-5.4-headers-5.4.0-51
sudo apt -f install
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```